Show Cargo Clippy lint statistics, summarizing all issues in a project
For a large project, running cargo clippy generates too many warnings. What is a clean way to get issue count (per lint name), without using an ugly (and unstable) text search?
I was able to do it with this, but it seems to be missing many cases:
cargo clippy --workspace --tests --bins --lib --benches --examples -- \
      -W clippy::pedantic 2>&1 \
      | rg --trim -- '-W clippy::' | sort | uniq -c | sort -h -r


Maybe you can use --message-format=json

Side note, --tests --bins --lib --benches --examples can be shortened to --all-targets

You could do it with jq:
cargo clippy  --all-targets --message-format=json | \
jq -s "[.[].message?.code?.code//empty]|group_by(.)[]|[.[0],length]"

Example output:
[
  "clippy::bind_instead_of_map",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::clone_on_copy",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::default_constructed_unit_structs",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::derivable_impls",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::expect_fun_call",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::needless_question_mark",
  2
]
[
  "clippy::needless_return",
  16
]
[
  "clippy::redundant_closure",
  2
]

